# Creating Dynamic checkboxGroupInput in Shiny package in R

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, checkboxlist

I need to create a group of check boxes using the checkBoxGroupInput from a data frame retrieved dynamically from the back end (Excel or database).  I can retrieve the desired column vector from the data-frame and show it as a 'dynamic' drop-down using the following code snippet:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggtern)
library(scales)

setwd("~/R/data")
library(XLConnect)
df <- readWorksheetFromFile("ternary_diagram_all.xlsx",sheet=1,startRow = 1, endCol=7)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
     titlePanel("VGLab Ternary Diagrams"),
     selectInput('wellName', 'Select Well', unique(df$Well))
  ),
```

I want to turn the unique values of the Well column for the df data frame into a set of check boxes that are rendered on the client.  I have looked up the documentation for the checkboxGroupInput, but do not know how to supply the list/vector for creating the check boxes.

Please advise.  I am a shiny beginner.

Thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you saw this in the documentation:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, width = NULL)
```

For the `choices` parameter, using `c(unique(df$Well))` should do it. `c()` creates a vector of the unique values in the chosen "Well" column.

Comment: Yes.  That works.  Actually, I did choices = unique(df$Well) and that worked fine.  I did not have to create a vector out of it.  R handled it for me.  There is a corresponding statement on the server side for subsetting the data frame based on the selected well which is: subset(df, Well %in% input$selectedWells).    The inputId is = 'selectedWells' from the checkboxGroupInput above.